# Write 4 byte hex from 4 byte number

Tags: c++

For a header file of a stream I need to write 4 bytes that represent a number (stream serial).

```
std::srand(time(0));
// Get a 4 byte number:
uint32_t t = static_cast<uint32_t>(std::rand());
```

Now I don't know how to get the hex representation of that number, something like
`1f ab 4e 83`. I tried a lot of the answers to similar questions (bit shifting, static_cast, and so on), but if I print the result, I only see strange symbols and not even 4 of them.

```
char serial_no[4] = {
    t & 0x000000FF,
    (t & 0x00FF0000) >> 8,
    (t & 0x0000FF00) >> 16,
    (t & 0xFF000000) >> 24
};
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen("C:/hex.txt","w");
fprintf(pFile, &serial_no[0]);
fprintf(pFile, &serial_no[1]);
fprintf(pFile, &serial_no[2]);
fprintf(pFile, &serial_no[3]);
fclose(pFile);
```

The file I wrote to, as I opened it with HexEdit, only showed 1 Byte. At least I expected to see 4 bytes.

For example, I also need to write 4 characters (4 byte) :

```
//                          O     g     g     S
char capture_pattern[4] = {0x4f, 0x67, 0x67, 0x53};
```

Here the console output returns O g g S, or as I open it in HexEdit, is `4f 67 67 53` as expected.
I want the same but for the number with LSB first.

Comment: Are you writing the bytes in big-endian or little-endian format?

Comment: `static_cast<uint32_t>(std::rand());` does not look like `C`

Comment: `(t & 0x0000FF00) >> 16` certainly results in 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: you want hex numbers printed as ascii, correct?  For example, you want

`int = 0x012345ab;` to show up as `0x01 0x23 0x45 0xab`, right?

In that case, your `fprintf` statements are incomplete.  You need:

```
pFile = fopen("C:/hex.txt","w");
fprintf(pFile, "0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[0]);
fprintf(pFile, "0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[1]);
fprintf(pFile, "0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[2]);
fprintf(pFile, "0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[3]);
fclose(pFile);
```

You are missing the second argument.  Take a look at the [function format](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html).

The following code shows the full example and another way to accomplish what you're trying to do:

Also, note that you're shifts are incorrect.  The code below fixes that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int t = 0x012345ab;

    char serial_no[4] = {
        t & 0x000000FF,
        (t & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
        (t & 0x00FF0000) >> 16,
        (t & 0xFF000000) >> 24
    };

    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[0]);
    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[1]);
    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[2]);
    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)serial_no[3]);
    printf("\n");

    int b = 0x012345cd;

    char arr[4] = {0};

    memcpy(arr, (unsigned char *)&b, sizeof(b));

    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)arr[0]);
    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)arr[1]);
    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)arr[2]);
    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)arr[3]);
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> $ Debug/test
>   0xab 0x45 0x23 0x01
>   0xcd 0x45 0x23 0x01

Answer (score 1):

Computation of `serial_no` needs fixing and recommended type change

```
unsigned char serial_no[4] = { t, t >> 8, t >> 16, t >> 24};
```

Add format:

```
//%x for hex, 02 to print at least 2 digits, hh to cast to char
fprintf(pFile, "%02hhx", serial_no[0]);
fprintf(pFile, "%02hhx", serial_no[1]);
fprintf(pFile, "%02hhx", serial_no[2]);
fprintf(pFile, "%02hhx", serial_no[3]);
```

or

```
fprintf(pFile, "%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx", t, t >> 8, t >> 16, t >> 24);
```

If you system does not understand `hh` because it is pre C99

```
fprintf(pFile, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", (unsigned char) t, 
     (unsigned char) (t >> 8), (unsigned char) (t >> 16), (unsigned char) (t >> 24));
```